# How to access current context in php mustache as a function?

Tags: php, mustache, mustache.php

Right now I have something like this in my mustache template:

```
{{#render}}{{widget}}{{/render}}
```

And I have a viewModel which contains this code:

```
public function render() {
    $View = $this->_View;
    return function($widgetName, Mustache_LambdaHelper $helper) use (&$View) {
        $widget = $helper->render($widgetName);
        return $helper->render($View->mustache->getPartialsLoader()->load("$widget.view"));
    };
}
```

I think you can see what I am trying to do here. I am trying to render a partial who's name is contained inside the widget-key of the current context.

Now the thing is, I really don't like the format I'm using in the template. I would prefer if I could write something like this:

```
{{renderWidget}}
```

then I would need to be able to access the current context directly in some way.

```
public function renderWidget() {
    return function($context) {
        return $helper->render($View->mustache->getPartialsLoader()->load("$context[widget].view"));
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me if that is possible in one way or another?